# Tableau Custom Geocoding - Ambiguous cities

Tags: geocoding, tableau-api

I have a lot of small towns (<15.000 population) from Germany in my data set, so Tableau (Desktop 10.3 Pro Version) has no geographical coordinates for them.

For this reason I made a .csv file (CustomGeo.csv is attached) with the following rows: Country (Name), State/Province, City, Latitude, Longitude. Also I created a schema.ini with the following content:

```
[CustomGeo.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
DecimalSymbol=,
Format=Delimited(;)
Col1="Country (Name)" Text
Col2="State/Province" Text
Col3="City" Text
Col4="Latitude" Double
Col5="Longitude" Double
```

Now, after I imported the csv file into Tableau (Map -> Geocoding ->  Import Custom Gecoding), I have more than 600 ambiguous cities and I don't understand why. There are big cities like Stuttgart and München which are tagged as ambiguous. Bigger cities in Germany can have more than one Postcode (PLZ).

The possibility to select the field State/Province under Edit Locations and State/Province does not change anything.

Here you can download the csv file and my data set with for geocoding important columns [hosted on google drive]:

[Custom Geocoding csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwe0f9w-TeBgZU1OemcteGs2RDQ)

[Data set](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwe0f9w-TeBgVlJxTkFTODcwOXc)

Be careful if you want to open the csv file with Excel. Excel could change the column format so the latitude and longitude data could be fucked up :)

I hope anyone can help me with that problem. I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution:
If you use the column names (Country (Name), State/Province, City, Latitude, Longitude) then you will extend an existing role. For bigger cities (>15000 population) Tableau has geo data. So if you extend the existing role with **all** cities in Germany you will have the bigger cities as well in your custom geocoding file. Because of that, the error with ambiguous cities will show up and bigger cities like München (Munich) or Stuttgart can not be displayed on the map.